# How to toggle checkbox state using jQuery in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox, toggle

On a form I have, there are two checkboxes, say Master and Slave. Whenever the master is checked, the slave needs to be checked (although slave could be unchecked by individually clicking on it). On the form load - the Master is set to check (default value) which means the slave also needs to be checked.

Then, I have some onChange event handler that manually checks and unchecks the slave based on the state of the master. This is where it doesn't work , just in IE. It works fine in other browsers. I have no idea why this is happening.

I am using jQuery and some css class that merely toggles between checked image and unchecked image. This is an issue only with the checkbox CSS (visual / graphic). The value is still true for that checkbox.

Here is the code

```
dojo.ready(function() { 
    // some code removed for simplicaity sake
$("#militaryOfficial").attr("checked", true);
$("#waiveTax").attr("checked", true);
}
$('#militaryOfficial').click('change', toggleTaxWaive);     
});

function toggleTaxWaive(){
if($("#militaryOfficial").is(':checked'))
{
    if(!$("#waiveTax").is(':checked'))
    {
        $("#waiveTax").trigger("click"); 
    }
}else
{
    $("#waiveTax").attr('checked', false);
}
}
```

The HTML is pretty basic. Adding as per requests in the comment

```
<div class="checkBox_Border">
 <span class="cds_spanCheck" style="background: url("/images/checkbox_nonSelect.png")     
 no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"></span>
 <span class="cds_spanCheck" style="background: url("/images/checkbox_Select.png") no-   
 repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;"></span>
 <input id="waiveTax" class="checkBox_innerWrap" type="checkbox" checked="checked"   
 value="true" name="waiveTax">
</div>
```

Please advise. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Or at least post it on fiddle.

Comment: There are several severe syntax errors in your posted code: This won't work anywhere. I guess it's just a copy-paste problem. E.g. addResetButton(); need "function(){" instead of ";" at the end.
However, you might try setting the checked property like so:
some_input.prop('checked', 'checked');
and unchecking it like that:
some_input.prop('checked', '');
Works for me in all browsers. Possibly IE confused true/false ...

Comment: @Nasmon . Thanks, yeah, those are not real error, I just hand modified the code to remove unwanted stuff. However, I tried both the checked -true and checked-checked ways but it didn't work for me. The solutions by Vinod mentioned below, works fine. Any idea why.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $("#Button1").click(function() {
               if ($('#Checkbox1').attr('checked')) {
                   Checkbox1.checked = false;
               }
               else {
                   Checkbox1.checked = true;
               }
           });
```

Comment: Vinod - this actually works ! This is amazing, I spent like so much time on this. I am curious - what made it work, what is different here  except some syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually an even simpler way, you just need to change the checkbox `checked` proprerty to `true` or `false`:

```
checkbox.on('click', toggleCheckbox);

function toggleCheckbox() { 
    if(checkbox[0].checked) checkbox[0].checked = false;
    else checkbox[0].checked = true;
}
```